# Infiniband ibv_asyncwatch usage

Tags: infiniband

I can see ibv_asyncwatch as part of libibverbs-utils package. 
I want to know its use cases. Like how can i use this to monitor asynchronous events. Could someone elaborate on this with example and what are options for it ?

Answer (score 0):

The InfiniBand specifications describe several unaffiliated asynchronous events. These events are not related to the operation of a specific QP, or to a specific verb. `ibv_asyncwatch` is an example program that monitor these events (on the first InfiniBand device) and prints the event type and the port on which it occurred.

You can see the complete list of events (including other asynchronous events) in the [`ibv_get_async_event` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ibv_get_async_event), and there are some more details on an [RDMAmojo blog post](http://www.rdmamojo.com/2012/08/11/ibv_get_async_event/). You can also read the (very short) [source code for `ibv_asyncwatch`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/libs/infiniband/libibverbs.git/tree/examples/asyncwatch.c).